# ReactJS: Unable to access latest parent state values from dynamically created sibling components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to share latest parent state value between multiple dynamically created child components?

Component A  creates an array of component B and store it in state(Array variable).
Component B has a button to print A's state length. Here each component B prints different values. They are not able to access latest A's state.

**A:**

```
const A = () => {
const [bList, setBList] = useState([]);
const [stateLength, setStateLength] = useState(0);

const addB = () => {
    let temp = <B state={printStatelength} />
    bList.push(temp)
    setBList([...bList]);
}

const printStatelength = () => {
    setStateLength(bList.length)
}

return (<>
    <button onClick={addB}>Add B</button>
    {stateLength}
    {bList}
</>);}
```

**B:**

```
    const B = (props) => {
   return (<button onClick={props.state} >print</button>);
}
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-firefly-18jfy)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of how you're rending the bList in the component A. When you do it the way you have, by pulling from the bList array, every element in that array (i.e. every instance of component B) seemingly has different values passed in to it for it bList.length. Thus, depending on which button you press, you are getting a different value.

If you map over the bList and render a B component for every element in the array, this should give you the result you want. In other words, change the return statement in component A to this:

```
return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addB}>Add B</button>
      {stateLength}
      {bList.map(() => (
        <B state={printStatelength} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
```